# vue: when navigate to other page only url changed

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i'm new to vue and i'm trying to navigate from one page to another (from home page in component  to profile page in view) using < route-link > but it changes only url not content of page, below all my code implementation for app.vue,profile.vue,home.vue,main.js and routes.js and i really dont know where did i mistake in, any  help please? and thanks in advance

```html
Home.vue 




  
<template>

  <div class="container" width=800px>

<ul>
  <li>
  {{question1.question}}
  <br>
  <br>

   </li>
  </ul>

  <b-row id="asked-info">
  <p>Asked by:  </p>
  
  <div id="user" v-for="(answer, index) in answers"
   :key="index"> 
 <router-link to="/profile"> {{ answer }}</router-link>
 
   
      </div>


  </b-row>
  </div>

</template>

<script>

export default {
 
  props: {
  
    question1: Object

  },
     data() {
    return {
     
      selectedIndex: null,
      
    };
  },
  
  computed: {
    answers() {
      let answers = [this.question1.correct_answer];
      // answers.push(this.question1.correct_answer);
      return answers;
    },
   
  },
 
}
</script>

Profile.vue
<template>

  <div class="container" width=800px>


  <b-row id="asked-info">
  <p>Welcome to the profile of:  </p>
  
  <div id="user" v-for="(answer, index) in answers"
   :key="index"> 
  
   {{ answer }}
      </div>
    
     


  </b-row>
 
  </div>

</template>
<script>
export default {
 
  props: {
  
    question1: Object

  },
  
  computed: {
    answers() {
      let answers = [this.question1.correct_answer];
      // answers.push(this.question1.correct_answer);
      return answers;
    },
  
  },
}
</script>


App.vue
<template>
 
  <div id="app">
   <Header />
   <b-container class="bv-example-row">
  <b-row>
  <b-col cols="8">
  <h1> Recently Asked </h1>

    <Home
  
    v-for="(question1,index) in questions" :key="index" 

     :question1="questions[index]"
    
      />
  
 
</template>

<script>

import Home from './components/Home.vue'
import Header from './components/Header.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Header,
    Home,
  
  },
  data(){
    return{
      questions: [],
      index: 0
     
     
    }
  },

</script>

routes.js

import Profile from './components/Profile.vue';
import Home from './components/Home.vue';



export const routes = [
  { path: "/", component: Home},
  { path: "/Profile", component: Profile },
  

]

main.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import { BootstrapVue} from 'bootstrap-vue'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
import {routes} from './routes'
import VueRouter from "vue-router";

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes
})
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your app.vue you're missing the `router-view` component :

```
<template>
 
  <div id="app">
   <Header />
   <b-container class="bv-example-row">
     <router-view></router-view>
    </b-container>
  <b-row>
  <b-col cols="8">
  <h1> Recently Asked </h1>

    <Home
  
    v-for="(question1,index) in questions" :key="index" 

     :question1="questions[index]"
    
      />
  
 
</template>

<script>

import Home from './components/Home.vue'
import Header from './components/Header.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Header,
    Home,
  
  },
  data(){
    return{
      questions: [],
      index: 0
     
     
    }
  },

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing out the tag `<router-view></router-view>`, which is where the component matched by the route will render. Just include it in your home.vue page where you want to.